# Opening window or context menu somewhere makes popup elements unfocusable (except buttons)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm

We have several popups that look like this:

```
   <Popup Name="Popup1" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Center" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=FirstGrid}" StaysOpen="True">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:MouseDragPopupBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPopupVisible}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPopupVisible}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CenterView}" Grid.Row="2">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Popup>
```

Basically, popups that are draggable, and whose visibility is bound to the viewmodel. The ItemsPanel is for adding UserControls (or to be exact, ViewModels that are bound to Views). This works generally very well.

The problem is when we open a context menu or another window somewhere else. This brings focus to that window or menu and the only way we can give focus to the Window again is to close it and reopen it.

*EDIT: I forgot to mention that focusing the window is not exactly the problem, but focusing the elements within the popup window: `textbox`, etc. No problems with `buttons` however!!*

We managed to solve this issue with Windows 10 and 8.1 by using this code on each View that we bind to the ItemsControl:

```
    private void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Application.Current.MainWindow.IsActive)
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
            this.Focus();
        }
    }
```

but it still doesn't work on our test Windows 8 or Windows 7 PCs, strangely!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement()` instead of `this.Focus()`.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan this does not work, thanks anyway

Comment: Downvotes, why? Sheesh.

Comment: I don't understand...what does that mean...I thought I've been thorough. And even if I weren't, I don't think that would necessitate me to delete a question. That's what edit's there for right? ;)

Comment: Complete reframing might change the shape of the question, so asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by hooking `Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();` on `MouseDown`, `MouseEnter`, and `MouseMove` of the UserControl's main grid, as well as on every child control (textbox, listbox, etc.).